# libpng error under VC6.0

Tags: opengl, png, visual-c++, libpng

I'm using **libpng** in my OpenGL project to load texture of png file with VC6.0 under windows xp.
It's OK to build and error occurs during running.
The error is

```
the instruction at 0x0040b4a3 referenced memory at 0x00000008 the memory could not be written
```

I've tried to reboot but error remains. And I've put the exe file to another xp desktop and error remains.

When debugging, I found this statement went wrong: (which is usually used with libpng)

```
png_read_png(png_ptr, info_ptr, PNG_TRANSFORM_STRIP_16 | PNG_TRANSFORM_PACKING | PNG_TRANSFORM_EXPAND, png_voidp_NULL);
```

Error message is

```
Unhandled exception in test.exe(NTDLL.DLL): 0xc0000005: Access Violation.
```

**My code works *fine* with g++ under fedora**, but something is wrong under VC6.0 with windows XP.

Source code is very large and I don't know what goes wrong, so I don't know what code to paste here.

Does any one has any idea about this?

I'll be very grateful if you can help me on this. Thx! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check the pointers passed into the function? One of them might have the value `8` instead of some valid memory address. If the data passed into libpng is fine, the error might be somewhere else.

Minor side note: Any reason for using VC++ 6.0 over any of the newer (and free) Express Editions?